# I am trying to stop hadoop services, but I get the error message like 'Error: root user required"

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I am trying to *stop hadoop services*, but I get the error message like

> **'Error:** root user required"

Someone please help me to solve this.

I am trying to learn hdfs basic commands.

Comment: Are you using any specific distribution like cdh or hdp? You can pick their Quickstart VM's. It is a good place to start if you just started learning.

Comment: On which platform you are trying to stop the service? If it is redhat or debian distribution use sudo to stop the services.

Comment: Hi @Avinash,

I am using centos, 

I tried to change the owner

sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs mkdir /user/training
sudo -u hdfs hadoop fs -chown training /user/training

But same error message, "error: root user required"

Do correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "root" user on *nix platforms is the all powerful user that can do anything.  It seems as if you aren't attempting to execute your commands with the highest possible privileged user, eg root.

If running from a command prompt, try running su first, to switch to root.

Comment: I tried to run the command su hdfs.. Its asking for the password. When I gave the password as training since i logged in as a training user, its displaying like 'incorrect password'

Comment: There is a password associated with the root account.  That password probably isn't the same as your training password.